What does the broken circle mean?
in the diagram attached, two circles enclose all of the wires.  What do the circles represent?  Thanks in advance.

Usually indicates a cable shield (e.g. coax/twinax cable). Sure there are duplicate questions but can't find one at the moment.

Some context would have been nice. What is the circuit for and what kind of signals are the wires carrying.

I don't think this is very well-standardized, but looking at the things these ellipses encircle: this is probably meant to say "5 is the connection to the shield of the cables carrying 4&7 as well as 8&9, respectively.
But that's an interpretation under the assumption that this is more of a electrical flow chart than an IC schematic diagram; in a context where 5 might be for example a current sense output, the dashed ellipses might also mean "measures the common mode current on these lines". TI uses (used?) that notation in some of their newer-generation class-D audio amplifier ICs.

Sorry - I have a DSUB connector that has 20 gauge wires (shielded) and I have to get them together but I’m not sure how I need to do that.  Is the circle telling me to butt splice them, solder sleeve, etc?

That's impossible to tell. All that we can interpret into that diagram is that there's a shield around these two pairs of wires, and that these shields are both connected to "5".

Okay - so the circle stands for shielding like adding braid?

possibly! You can, for example, find microphone cable with two insulated conductors surrounded by a braid, or in USB2 cables, you'll often find both data lines surronded by a variety of shield materials; you can find networking cable (CAT7, I think?) where the four twisted pairs in the cable are individually wrapped in conductive foil; SATA cables (for hard drives) have a twinaxial conductor setup (but I doubt that's what you're dealing with here). There's very many different kinds of cables with shields!
